# Folded n-dimensional gaussian integral

Tags: integration, field-theory, gaussian-integral

I am dealing with the following integral:
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty} dx_1 \ldots \int_0^{\infty} dx_n \quad e^{-J^T x - x^T A x}
\end{equation}
Is there any general analytical solution which gives the above integral in terms of the determinant of $A$, $J$ and (I guess) the error function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I didn't notice the domain was different. Please ignore this answer.

<s>This is standard in quantum field theory. Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_integrals_in_quantum_field_theory#Gaussian_integrals_in_higher_dimensions) or any book on the topic.</s>

Comment: the domain is different .... having only positive values makes it much more not-trivial to solve

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't notice it. Should I delete my answer? In the meantime I updated it.